# Is this a fontspec bug or a font bug

Tags: fonts, fontspec, luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lining numbers not working in certain fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/lining-numbers-not-working-in-certain-fonts)

I want to use the OpenType features of the Calibri font, but things are getting weird here! I am using LuaLaTeX from the latest TeX Live, but the problem is the same with older versions or with XeLaTeX.

The test document creates two blocks of four lines containing variations of the number `111` in different styles. The first four lines are done with `\addfontfeatures`, the second four lines with `\newfontfamily`. As far as I understand `fontspec` both blocks should look the same.

While this is true for a lot of OTF-Fonts (TeX Gyre xxx, Calluna Sans, Myriad Pro...) it is not with Calibri. For Calibri there is no change between monospaced and proportional in the first (`\addfontfeatures`) block.

Is this a bug in `fontspec` or in Calibri?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\fontspec[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}] {Calibri}
\newfontfamily\NumTL[Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\NumTO[Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\NumPL[Numbers={Proportional,Lining}]{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\NumPO[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Calibri}

111 {\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}} 111} 111

111 {\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}} 111} 111

111 {\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,Lining}} 111} 111

111 {\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}} 111} 111

\bigskip

111 {\NumTL 111} 111

111 {\NumTO 111} 111

111 {\NumPL 111} 111

111 {\NumPO 111} 111

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: [Lining numbers not working in certain fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10986/2693). When you use `\addfontfeatures` with conflicting specifications it depends on the font how they will be handled.