# addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle} doesn't always work

Tags: fontspec, oldstylenums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lining numbers not working in certain fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10986/lining-numbers-not-working-in-certain-fonts)

In the following example, the line with an exclamation sign should be in oldstyle figures:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}#1}}

\begin{document}
\Large
{\fontspec[Numbers=Lining]{LinBiolinum_R.otf}
1234567890

\oldstylenums{1234567890}}

{\fontspec[Numbers=OldStyle]{LinBiolinum_R.otf}
1234567890

\oldstylenums{1234567890}}

{\fontspec[Numbers=Lining]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
1234567890

\oldstylenums{1234567890} !}

{\fontspec[Numbers=OldStyle]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
1234567890

\oldstylenums{1234567890}}

\end{document}
```

Why isn't it? `Biolinum` is a companion sans font and the definition of `\oldstylenums` works for it.

Comment: Interesting thing. It seems that `Numbers=OldStyle` successfully overwrite `Numbers=Lining` for Biolinum (as it should) but not for Libertine. Can you be satisfied with a solution using [`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) (= Are you using Libertine/Biolinum in your whole document anway)?