# current font family using fontspec

Tags: fontspec

I'm trying to emulate the behaviour of a [pdf]LaTeX package that provides commands `\lstyle`, `\ostyle`, `\tstyle`, and `\pstyle` to activate lining, oldstyle, tabular and proportional figures, respectively.  But they are *context-dependent* so that, for example, `\lstyle` might be Proportional,Lining or Monospaced,Lining, depending on the current features.  With traditional font selection commands I can use `\f@family` to determine which family is current.  Is there some way of doing this using `fontspec`?  The cautionary note in the documentation for `\addfontfeatures` suggests otherwise.

Comment: `\f@family` continues to store the name of the current font family. It does not obey ‘rules’ about a trailing `j` or `x`, though.

Comment: It's actually font *features* that I need access to in the fontspec environment. I have found definitions of \IfFontFeatureExists and \IfFontFeatureActive in an answer to an earlier question.  I think the latter will solve my problem.

Comment: \IfFontFeatureExists works but the following definition doesn't:\cs_new_eq:NN \IfFontFeatureActive \mico_fontfeature_if_active:nTF. What's wrong?

Comment: Not answering your question in the comment, but the discussion in the following question about how `\addfontfeatures` works might be useful to you. [Lining numbers not working in certain fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10986)

Comment: I'm not using \addfontfeatures, I'm using \newfontfamily; but to know which features to activate, I need to know which features are already active.