# Changing font of numbers (Importing from a different font)

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, oldstylenums, liningnums

I want to use `\usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}`, but without the oldstyle numbers. I wanted to change the font of Sans Serif numbers to Helvetica, Epigrafica, ..., so I can use lining numbers.

Maybe it is similar to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7100/change-font-of-mathematics-numbers) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312346/importing-%c3%9f-from-a-different-font), but I could not adapt these solutions to my problem.

Also, I cannot use XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Update: It seems to be not possible to import some characters from other fonts in text mode, as appointed by @Davïd and @Henri-Menke. :/

Thanks everybody!

Comment: From the Readme: »The only figure style supported is proportional semi-oldstyle.«  Sorry, but it seems you are out of luck.  You could substitute the lining number from another font, but that would look very awkward.

Comment: Indeed, "lining" numbers are [not included in the glyph set](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/merriweather). You could perhaps note your interest on the [github issue tracker](https://github.com/EbenSorkin/Merriweather/issues).

Comment: You could also switch to another font.  [Chaparral Pro](https://typekit.com/fonts/chaparral-pro) comes to my mind, which is unfortunately commercial but a superb slab serif type face.  A subset comes bundled with Adobe InDesign and Adobe Illustrator.  If you have one of the programs, you have the font and may legally use it.

Comment: And *possibly* related, see an earlier question (that got no real answer, perhaps because there isn't one): "[Two different 'main fonts' in use; use only one for numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296247/46980)."

Comment: If you are able to use a different font, then [XCharter](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/xcharter/) (+ on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcharter)) gets you some of the character of Merriweather, imo. (So would [Vollkorn](http://vollkorn-typeface.com/), but I don't think there's a "package" for it?)

Answer (score 1):

This answer was shamelessly stolen from Alan Munn's answer in [Lining numbers not working in certain fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10993/89976), and modified to the Merriweather font. Here, the numbers are replaced by Helvetica.

> Note that this does require you to use the macro `\lining` to set the
>   font. It would therefore not change every number, which I believe is what you are asking. Here you would have to use the macro in section numbers and basically everywhere. It is just a local change.

As others, and me, have pointed out in this and other posts, switching some symbols from fonts generally doesn't look very good. I'd either switch to a different font or accept the old style numbers included in the font.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}
 \newfontface\lining[Numbers=Lining]{Helvetica}
\begin{document}
Foo\lining 1234567890
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again :), but this code changes the style for page and Chapter/Section numbering?

Comment: Sorry, no, this doesn't

Comment: Also, I need to use pdfLatex.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit your needs? (mostly copied from [[Fischer (2010)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7510/10995)])

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{merriweather}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{phv}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}
\begin{document}
Hello Text 1234

$Hello Math 1234$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think O.T. needs to change the numbers everywhere, including section numbers, enumerate and basically just a global change.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but almost... I need the lining figures outside the math environment.

Comment: @CostaPR Then you have to use another font for the whole document.  Loading single charaters from a different font is not possible in text mode.  (Barring some active character solution).